# Import xml file to sql server table without bulkcopy

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I want to store xmlfile data into sql server table, i want to achieve this by without using bulk query.

---table stucture--
CREATE TABLE XMLData_tbl
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)
here i want to store xml data from file to XmlData column. Is there any other way to load apart from using openrowset(bulk,)?

Comment: What is wrong with the `FROM OPENROWSET(BULK...`?

Comment: i am using AWS, it doesn't support 'bulkadmin' role for users.

Comment: What about bcp? Is it legit in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program to open the file and grab what you want from the file and then execute a stored procedure to insert the data?  Not sure we have enough information about your requirements.

Are you required to go straight from file to database?
Do you need to manipulate the data before sending to database?
Are the files very big and they are taking forever to open with openrowset?

Comment: its straigt from file to database. I am using AWS it doen't support bulkadmin role for user so.